# Scala Type inference for anonymous function declaration

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, type-inference

I'm a beginner in Scala and I'm just curious about how Scala handles the type inference for this code snippet

```
trait Expression { .... }

def eval (binding : String => Boolean) : Expression => Boolean
```

I understand that binding is a function that converts `String` to `Boolean`, but why `binding` at the same time could be declared as a member of `Expression`? is it implicitly converted? How does it work?

Sorry if my question is a bit confusing

Thanks so much :D

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? What type-inference are you talking about? There is no type-inference in the code you posted, all types are explicitly declared.

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely no type inference going on here, as Jörg W Mittag says.

```
def eval (binding : String => Boolean) : Expression => Boolean
```

is simply an abstract method declaration (abstract because it doesn't have a body). It can be implemented in different ways, depending on the definition of `Expression`.

> why `binding` at the same time could be declared as a member of `Expression`

It can't, given just what you posted.

Answer (score 4):

I think the key point is that, function `eval` returns a function, whose type is `Function2[Expression, Boolean]`.

It's more clear to say:

```
def eval (binding : String => Boolean) : (Expression => Boolean)
```

There is no direct relationship between `binding` and `Expression`.